# How to call resource request in a foreach loop in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

As I read right from the Gatling documentation, `foreach` loop expects `ChainBuilder` as an executable expression.

> foreach(sequence, elementName){chain} The chain is repeated for every
> element in the sequence and the current element is stored in the
> Session under the elementName key

However, if I want to use it inside `resource` method, it expects `HttpRequestBuilder`s. Here's my usecase:

```
.exec(
  http("Some name.")
    .get("/api/call1?viewType=REGULAR")
    .check(
      jsonPath("$..reviewers[*]").ofType[Seq[Any]].saveAs("reviewers")
    )
    .resources(
      foreach(session => session("reviewers").as[Seq[Any]], "reviewer") {
        http("Request resource.")
          .get("/api/users/${reviewer}/photo")
          .headers(resourceRequestHeaders)
      }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible as of Gatling 3.3 (and upcoming 3.4). Number of requests in the `resources` can only be static.

Comment: I wonder if there is a plan to add such capability to next versions of Gatling?